# how i can have a container in dropdown navbar?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I want to create a navbar like this site: digikala.com

my problem is when the mouse goes on menu item drop-down on mouse hover and open a container for all links to show in right
I want to know how I can have a container like this site?

I use bootstrap 4.6 in this page

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" style="color: purple;" href="#">Partineh</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <!-- <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li> -->
      <li class="nav-item">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                          <h5>دسته بندی کالاها</h5>
                        </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <div class="menu-grid">

              <div class="btn-group dropleft">
                <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                              Dropleft
                            </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
                  <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
                  <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
                  <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="btn-group dropleft">
                <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                              Dropleft1
                            </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-12">
                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action1</button>
                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action1</button>
                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here1</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">سوپرمارکت</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: do you want the dropdown to show when you hover on the div or whatever it is

Comment: pls also try to add your css or anything you're using to force the dropdown to display like javascript